# Components in Angular are kind Of Directives?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-directives, angular7

As said,

> Directives are instructions in the DOM

so as components work as *the instructions in DOM too*.

**So that Means Components are Directives too but with a template**
is it right to said so?

i am having difficulty in clearing the difference and comparison of both.

(*Preparing for First Angular Job Interview*)

Comment: Yes a Component extends a Directive: `export interface Component extends Directive` (source code), so all components are directives, but not all directives are components

Comment: @PierreDuc : Thank You.  So on asking i can say there is no difference except a template in components or Extended directive with a template is component?

Comment: Yes, technically speaking a directive is to alter behaviour of an element in a uniform way. A component is an encapsulation of certain elements to execute a goal